# Anypoint Platform - Connect API Manager with Cloudhub App using Autodiscovery ID

Tags: mule, mulesoft, cloudhub, ibm-api-management, autodiscovery

- I have designed an API using **API Designer** and I deployed it in **API
  Manager**.
- Then, I have imported the API from API Designer in my
  application/project from **Anypoint Studio**.
- I have added an **autodiscovery** configuration. I set the flow which has
  the HTTP Listener with the API Kit Router and the ID from API
  Manager.
- I have deployed the application in **Cloudhub**.
- When I go to API Manager the status is **Unregistered**.

This is the API Configuration that I have:

[image]

Using the URL from Cloudhub as the Implementation URI.

**Am I doing all the steps correctly? Why doesn't the API detect the implementation?**

Comment: Think that's fine. It can take quite a few minutes to turn to registered after the app starts. In the application log, do you see a message saying something like 'API instance... unblocked '?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you configure the Autodiscovery Element with the correct values as they appear in the API Manager
[image]

```
 <api-platform-gw:api apiName="<API Name>" version="<API Version>" flowRef="api-main" create="false" apikitRef="api-config" doc:name="API Autodiscovery" />
```

Also the API belong to an Environment so make sure In the Runtime Manager you are setting the environment client id and secret when deploy the application in Cloudhub:

[image]

The get the client id an secret for the specific Environment navigate to Anypoint Platform -> Access Management -> Environment.

Hope this helps...